# Full query on the table in two db schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two database schemas with the same table (columns: ID, first name, last name, value).

Database 1 values:

```
1, John, Goodman, 5
2, Peter, Snow, 6
3, Mike, Walker, 7
4, John, Goodman, 8
```

Database 2 values:

```
1, Peter, Snow, 2
2, Bobby, White, 1
3, Mike, Walker, 1
4, Brad, West, 2
```

I want to write and query that will give me this result,
i.e., summary from both tables (left and right):

```
Number, First Name, Last Name, Table.DB1, Table.DB2
---------------------------------------------------
1, John, Goodman, 13, 0
2, Peter, Snow, 6, 2
3, Mike, Walker, 7, 1
4, Bobby, White, 0, 1
5, Brad, West, 0, 2
```

How can I do it ?

Note that this is the simplified version of the my schema, because I have
some joins in this query, too .

Comment: Your desired results aren't matching with your sample data.  Can we assume that is just a typo?  Also, will both tables have all ids or could one have some and the other have different?

Comment: Where does `ID = 5` and `name = Brad` come from for example?

Comment: I made a type, its fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After rereading your question, it sounds like you want to `JOIN` on the `name` fields, not maintaining any sort of `ID`.  Assuming that's the case, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to geneate the `id` and `FULL OUTER JOIN` to get results from both tables:

```
SELECT Row_Number() Over (order by (select null)) ID, 
    COALESCE(t1.Name,t2.Name) Name, 
    COALESCE(t1.Value,0) T1Value, 
    COALESCE(t2.Value,0) T2Value
FROM databasename.schemaname.table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN databasename.schemaname.table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
```

Please note, there is no specific ordering for the new ID.

Comment: Yes, but I need to join on multiple columns, not only on name. For example, on first name and last name, how can I do this ?

Comment: This also won't quite fulfill the criteria - you need to `SUM` the values and `GROUP BY` the names like so: `SELECT Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ID, COALESCE(t1.Name,t2.Name) Name,     SUM(COALESCE(t1.Value,0)) T1Value, SUM(COALESCE(t2.Value,0)) T2Value
FROM table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name GROUP BY t1.name, t2.name` Excuse the crap formatting in the comment.

Comment: @Milan - if you needed multiple columns then that should have been part of the question otherwise how can anyone know that's what you need? But you can just add another condition to the join, there's no magic to it.

Comment: @Steve, I rephrased my question. Thx.

Comment: @Milan -- you probably should read up on `JOIN`.  You can add as many fields you like to the `ON` clause.  Here's a good article: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @StevePettifer -- good point, thanks for the comment.  This question has had quite a few iterations...

Comment: @Milan - Still the same. See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec65e/3) which just expands on sgeddes answer.

Comment: O.K. I understand. I have just one more question, in this case, how can I inner join one more table (on some columns) with databasename.schemaname.table2 ?

Comment: Take a look at the link sgeddes provided. Joins are easy really, it just a case of linking tables through common data.

Comment: I know joins, but I don't know in this case how to join some table3 with table2 ?

Comment: @Milan -- try this.  Good luck.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59e69/3.  If this doesn't work though, try something else and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: @sgeddes  I have one problem with full outer join. E.g. if I have Five Bobby's in table 1 and one in table 2, it will sum Bobby's five time from the table 2, too ?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you are comparing via name and not via ID.

Just use an outer join

```
SELECT db1.Name, 

case when db1.Value is null then 0 else db1.Value, 

case when db2.Value is null then 0 else db2.Value

FROM db1

FULL OUTER JOIN db2 on db1.Name = db2.Name
```

You can swap the `case when` with a [COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) expression as well.